# Kotlin Generic function type return child class

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to create a class where generic operations can be performed on classes that has inherited from it. I have tried using sealed classes, inline functions to no success, hopefully someone can provide some insight on this.

Example

```
class Base {
    fun add // does the operation
}
data class A(val a: Int, val b: Int) : Base
data class B(val c: Int, val d: Int) : Base
val example =  A(1,2)
example.add(A(3,4))
println(example)
// A(4,6)
val example2 = B(5,6)
example2.add(B(7,8))
println(example2)
// B(12, 14)
```

Comment: Are you trying to make `add` return the right type, or automatically figure out how to add two `A`s?

Comment: add should return the right type, and ensures that the class is a subclass of Base

Comment: @Keyute can you elaborate more on why `add` method return type is non-existent in your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is self-referential generics.

```
abstract class Base<B : Base<B>> {
  abstract fun add(other: B): B
}
data class A(...) : Base<A>
data class B(...) : Base<B>
```

Comment: this gives me the error One Type argument expected for class

Comment: Fixed the typo.

Comment: this solution certainly solves the part 1 of my problem. question is, is it possible to have the add function not abstract since it uses reflection to get the job done

Comment: No, it is not possible with the types you've described.

Comment: alright, the proposed solution works well enough. Thank you!